# Using a normal tyre on an emergency wheel

Tags: tires, spare-tire

One of my friends discovered a car-sharing vehicle, all four wheels of which were replaced by the emergency wheels, but it seemed to have normal tyres on it. Here's the picture of one of its wheels (the car is Russian-spec VW Polo).

As stated on the rim it's not safe to use it permanently, but all info that I've found was regarding the tyre. And this car has a set of normal sized (185/16) ones.

So my question is (out of curiosity, not that I had an intention to drive it) - what exactly will happen to this car? Will rims fail?

[image]

Comment: I don't have any empirical data, but I would think it would the rims wouldn't matter too much, though they'd be skinnier than regular rims. The tires are the most important here. I'm betting in the case of the image above, their car had the wheels/tires stolen and they had to come up with a "cheap" solution to get it back on the road ... they then stole the spares out of the other cars and put regular tires on them. Not what I'd call a bright move.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yeah, I actually can't imagine what had happened to this poor car. But - are those rims the same as ordinary metal rims, or they're made from some different material?  For instance, cheap bicycle rims are much weaker than quality ones. So I wonder if it's the case here?

Comment: I'd suggest they are made of the same metal and basic structure as a "normal" steel rim ... the only real difference would be the width, because donut tires are most often narrower than regular tires. It seems to me putting regular sized tires on these rims would make for a less stable driving experience. Wide tires on narrow rims have a tendency to have play back and forth due to there not being as much support for the tire.